# add "are you sure you want to leave page without saving" on form with colorbox popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, colorbox

I have a form on a popup colorbox and if the user edits one of the textboxes and then they hit cancel I want a popup that displays something like "are you sure you want to leave without saving?".  Currently i have the popup showing but it is showing after the popup colorbox is already closed

TABLE OF USERS PAGE

```
 $('a.openDialog').colorbox({
                iframe: true,
                transition: "elastic",
                width: "75%", height: "90%"
            });
```

ACTUAL FORM PAGE

```
 $(':input', 'form').bind("change", function () {
                setConfirmUnload(true);
             });


function setConfirmUnload(on) {

              window.onbeforeunload = (on) ? unloadMessage : null;
          }

          function unloadMessage() {
              return 'You have entered new data on this page.' +
        ' If you navigate away from this page without' +
        ' first saving your data, the changes will be' +
        ' lost.';
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use colorbox callbacks onCleanup or onClose if that doesn't help you can add a listener on the close button or div

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution, you have to call the oncomplete function of colorbox here's the code

```
$("#cboxClose").click(function (e) {

                        // stop any other script from firing
                        e.stopPropagation();

                        if (confirm('You have unsaved changes, are you sure that you want to cancel? All of your changes will be lost.')) {
                            $.colorbox.close();
                            // ensure that the binding is removed when closed
                            $("#cboxClose").unbind();
                        }

                    });

                } // close oncomplete
```